# global rule to be applied to all current rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I currently have a pretty straight forward modrewrite file that maps urls to different php pages with possible GET variables:

```
RewriteRule ^grant$ about.php?p=4 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-people-([A-za-z0-9-]+)$ about.php?p=5&to=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)-media$ media-gallery-element.php?prettyid=$1 [L]
#etc .... it goes on for perhaps 200 or so entries
```

I want to have a global language variable that is in the url and I'm wondering how I can smartly adjust my modrewrite file to handle this.  I could do it by doubling my entries and just add more rules such that the first one above gets changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^grant$ about.php?p=4&lan=en [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/grant$ about.php?p=4&lan=$1 [L]
```

The first row is just the same and would default to english (en) and then the second row handles other language codes, es, fr, de, etc.  So I could do it this way, but it seems like there is a better way to do this without doubling my entries.  Basically, I want to take ALL of my requests, look for a ([a-z]+)/ at the beginning of the request uri, and then tack that onto the request as a GET variable, lan.

How do I do this smartly?

Comment: Do you have a finite list of languages?

Comment: Well i'm using mod-rewrite in apache in linux, and php is my language of choice

Comment: Not programming languages: Human languages.  Like "lan=xx" where xx is the language.

Comment: ohh, haha, I should have realized that. Currently it's just english and spanish, but we are going to soon add french, german, arabic and hopefully more in the future.  So, I guess, no, the list is not finite right now and will have to accommodate more languages in the future.

Comment: That's finite enough for the purpose of making a rule that matches all available languages...

Comment: Ok, so what's the best way of doing that given my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily by setting an environmental variable. Something like this should do the trick:

```
# set default environmental variable for language
RewriteRule .* - [E=language:en]

# if two characters and slash lead, then
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$     

# overwrite default environmental variable
RewriteRule .* - [E=language:%1] 

# other rules
RewriteRule ^grant$ about.php?p=4&lan=%{ENV:language} [L]
```

You can also access the environmental variable directly in PHP, in which case you could skip including it in the rewrite rules:

```
echo getenv('language');
echo $_SERVER['language'];
echo $_SERVER['REDIRECT_language'];
```